# Error trying to reach github route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to change the beta router to the new component router,
   my project started from the official angular2 seed: https://github.com/angular/angular2-seed

So this is how my **seed-app.ts** looks like:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, Routes, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';

import {Home} from './components/home/home';
import {About} from './components/about/about';
import {RepoBrowser} from './components/repo-browser/repo-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'seed-app',
  providers: [],
  pipes: [],
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  styles: [require('./seed-app.scss')],
  template: require('./seed-app.html'),
})
@Routes([
  { path: '/home',       component: Home},
  { path: '/about',      component: About},
  { path: '/github/...', component: RepoBrowser},
])
export class SeedApp {

  constructor() {}

}
```

and this is the template for the seed-app:

```
<div class="seed-app">
  <h3>
    Angular 2 Seed
  </h3>
  <nav>
    <a [routerLink]=" ['/home'] ">
      Home
    </a>
    |
    <a [routerLink]=" ['/about'] ">
      About
    </a>
    |
    <a [routerLink]=" ['/github/repo-list', {org: 'angular'}] ">
      Github Repos
    </a>
  </nav>

  <main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </main>


  <footer>
    © 2016
  </footer>
</div>
```

All the routes are working except I can't reach the github route at all, getting this error:

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot match any routes.
>   Current segment: 'github'. Available routes: ['/home', '/about',
>   '/github/...'].

If it helps this is the code for the **repo-browser.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Router, Routes, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';

import {RepoList} from '../repo-list/repo-list';
import {RepoDetail} from '../repo-detail/repo-detail';
import {Github} from '../../services/github';

@Component({
  selector: 'repo-browser',
  template: require('./repo-browser.html'),
  styles: [require('./repo-browser.scss')],
  providers: [ Github ],
  directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ],
  pipes: []
})
@Routes([
  {path: '/:org',       component: RepoList},
  {path: '/:org/:name', component: RepoDetail },
])
export class RepoBrowser {

  constructor(private router: Router, private github: Github) {}

  searchForOrg(orgName: string) {
    this.github.getOrg(orgName)
      .subscribe(({name}) => {
        console.log(name);
        this.router.navigate(['RepoList', {org: orgName}]);
      });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To github you can give anchor element with href

```
 <a href="/github/repo-list/angular">
  Github Repos
</a>
```

Comment: True but it has some problems for example I'm using the '#' route strategy so I'll have to use "#/github/repo-list/angular" but later I will want to use the location history strategy and I don't want to change links in my app, there needs to be a more angular way of doing it